# Inner Join in cassandra CQL

Tags: cassandra

How do I write subqueries/nested queries in cassandra. Is this facility is provided in CQL?

Example I tried:

```
cqlsh:testdb> select itemname from item where itemid = (select itemid from orders where customerid=1);
```

It just throws the following error -

```
Bad Request: line 1:87 no viable alternative at input ';'
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Because of its distributed nature, Cassandra has no support for RDBMS style joins. You have a few options for when you want something like a join.

One option perform separate queries and then have your application join the data itself. This makes sense if the data is relatively small and you only have to perform a small number of queries. Based on the example you gave above, this would probably be a good solution for you.

For more complicated joins, the usual strategy is to denormalize the data and store a *materialized view* of the join. The advantage to this is that fetching this data will be much faster than having to build it join in your application every time you need it. The cost is now you have multiple places where you are storing the same data and you will need to keep it all in sync. You can either update all your views when new data comes into the system or you can have a periodic batch job that rebuilds thems.

You might find this article useful: [Do You Really Need SQL to Do It All in Cassandra?](https://maxgrinev.wordpress.com/2010/07/12/do-you-really-need-sql-to-do-it-all-in-cassandra/) Its a bit old but its principles still apply.

Comment: Since begin 2015, Cassandra also supports JOINS, pretty much like RDBMS style. It requires installing DataStax ODBC or Apache SparkSQL. Read more in http://www.datastax.com/2015/03/how-to-do-joins-in-apache-cassandra-and-datastax-enterprise. Drivers here: https://academy.datastax.com/downloads/download-drivers

Comment: Not really. Cassandra still has no native support for joins. Sure, you can pull all your data from Cassandra into Spark and then do joins in Spark, but then you are using Spark, not Cassandra. DSE makes that integration easier, but DSE is not Apache Cassandra.

Comment: maxgrinev website where the article is hosted is out of service.