# Joins support in Cassandra

Tags: join, cassandra

Is there any way to achieve joins in Cassandra. If not, are there any alternative ways to achieve it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to do a join queries with 2 or more tables in cassandra cql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17248232/how-to-do-a-join-queries-with-2-or-more-tables-in-cassandra-cql)

Comment: Cassandra does not support JOIN. Your schema should be in de-normalized form.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Inner Join in cassandra CQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16790297/inner-join-in-cassandra-cql)

Answer (score 0):

JOINs are not supported in Cassandra - typically, the 'right' fix is to denormalize your data so that you can achieve your query with either 1 single SELECT.