# Some queries in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra

I created database "Movies" with three column families:

```
CREATE TABLE movies (
    movie_id int primary key,
    title text,
    avg_rating decimal,
    total_ratings int,
    genres set<text>
);

# shows all ratings for specific movie
CREATE TABLE ratings_by_movie (
    movie_id int,
    user_id int,
    rating decimal,
    ts int,
    primary key(movie_id, user_id)
);

# show all ratings of specific user
CREATE TABLE ratings_by_user (
    user_id int,
    movie_id int,
    rating decimal,
    ts int,
    primary key(user_id, movie_id)
);
```

Is it possible to make the following queries?

1. Show the movie with the most reviews
2. Show all movies with the average rating >= 4
3. Show 100 best movies based on their ratings

Comment: Show the query you have attempted so far

Comment: 1. In PostgreSQL i can do something like this: `select movie_id, count(rating) as c from movierating
       group by (movie_id)  
       order by c desc limit 1;` But I dont know how I can use count across the specific column in Cassandra (column rating -  in my case)
2. I have no idea how i can calculate average value in Cassandra.

Answer (score 1):

Cassandra = No Joins. Your model is 100% relational. You need to rethink it for Cassandra. I would advice you take a look at these slides. They dig deep into how to model data for cassandra. Also here is a webinar covering the topic. But stop thinking foreign keys and joining tables, because if you need relations cassandra isn't the tool for the job.

**But Why?**

Because then you need to check consistency and do many other things that relational databases do and so you loose the performance and scalability that cassandra offers.

**What can I do?**

DENORMALIZE! Lots of data in one table? But the table will have too many columns!
So? Cassandra can handle a very large number of columns in a table.

For more details check: [How to do a join queries with 2 or more tables in cassandra cql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17248232/how-to-do-a-join-queries-with-2-or-more-tables-in-cassandra-cql)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! So my queries are not possible in the way I created my tables (without using Spark)?