# Common table expression (CTE) in Apache Cassandra

Tags: sql, database, cassandra, nosql

I had a SingleStore database and I decided to switch to Apache Cassandra, transferred all the tables with data, and decided to test the queries. Cassandra doesn't understand "WITH" Clause.

`WITH t AS (SELECT * FROM tt), ...`

[image]

> Cassandra does not follow the relational model. Data is modeled on the
> query. Joins and sub-queries are not supported. Data denormalization
> and table duplication are required.

From [I haven't found anything else about this problem other than this.](https://www.instaclustr.com/blog/apache-cassandra-for-the-sql-server-developer/)

I wanted to know what options there are to get out of the situation.

The only idea is to put all the data in one table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TL;DR there are no *joins* with C*. See [this earlier thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17248232/how-to-do-a-join-queries-with-2-or-more-tables-in-cassandra-cql) and answers.

I think you need a basic training how to come from RDBMS to Cassandra world and I believe these below links would work out for you to better understand this side,

- [Moving from RDBMS to NoSQL C* blog](https://www.datastax.com/blog/best-practices-migrating-relational-data-platform-apache-cassandratm)
- [Academy for free training](https://datastax.academy/)
- [A free browser-based tutorial hub](https://www.datastax.com/dev)

Comment: I wanted to update the answer. If you're using [a fully-managed serverless DBaaS offering Astra DB](https://docs.datastax.com/en/astra-serverless/docs/quickstart/qs-graphql-cql-first.html), there you get GraphQL which allows you to combine results from more than 1 table.