# Using INNER JOIN on Cassandra

Tags: php, cassandra

Can I use INNER JOIN in Cassandra ?

```
SELECT * FROM device,device_token WHERE device_token.id_phone = device.id
```

If I cannot use inner join. What type of query I can use in cassandra instead for inner join?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Inner Join in cassandra CQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16790297/inner-join-in-cassandra-cql)

Answer (score 1):

There are no joins in Cassandra.

Most people denormalize i.e. insert the data multiple times into the rows where it is needed.  Cassandra is designed for extremely fast writes so increasing the insert workload is normally a good tradeoff.

You can also do a separate query and join manually, but this is normally slower.

Answer (score 0):

You can use collections to model joins. Look as set, list, map and docs about it: http://www.datastax.com/docs/1.2/cql_cli/using/collections