# Real time complex queries on Cassandra

Tags: cassandra

We're looking for a tool (preferably open source) which helps us to perform complex queries (advanced filtering and joins, no need full SQL) in real time.

Assume that all the data needed fits in memory, and we want to avoid, if possible, the overhead of map reduce tools.

To be more specific, we need to load n partitions of a single table, and join them by clustering column.

```
Variables Table:
Variable ID: Partition key
Person ID: Clustering key
Variable Value

Desired output columns:
Person ID, Variable 1 Value, Variable 2 Vale, ..., Variable N Value
```

We can achieve it by an in-memory load-filter-join process, but we were wondering if there's any tool out there with this use case covered out of the box and with a fair performance.

We've tested Spark, but the partitioning of Spark C* connector is based on the primary key, so each Variable ID would be loaded in a different Spark node, and the join process would be really slow (all the data would travel all over the Spark cluster).

Any tips? known tools?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16790297/inner-join-in-cassandra-cql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that you have a number of options to perform this task:

- **Rethink your database schema**, denormalize it. `var_id:person_id:value` rows are not the best table schema if you want to query by person_id (and it smells really bad as an [entity-attribute-value db antipattern](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/93124/eav-is-it-really-bad-in-all-scenarios)):

> EAV gives a flexibility to the developer to define the schema as needed and this is good in some circumstances. On the other hand it performs very poorly in the case of an ill-defined query and can support other bad practices. In other words, EAV gives you enough rope to hang yourself and in this industry, things should be designed to the lowest level of complexity because the guy replacing you on the project will likely be an idiot.

You can use schema with multiple columns (cassandra can handle a lot of them):

```
create table person_data (
  person_id int primary key,
  var1 text,
  var2 text,
  var3 text,
  var4 text,
  ....
);
```

If you don't have a predefined set of variables, you can use cql3 collections like map for storing the data in a more flexible way.

- **Create a secondary index on person_id** (even it's a clustering key already). You can query for all data for a specific user without using joins, but with some issues:

  - As your query will hit multiple partitions, it will require not a single disk seek, but a series of them, so your query latency may be higher than you're expecting.
  - secondary indexes are not free: C* must perform more work under the hood if you insert a row to a table with indexed columns.
- **Use external index** like ElasticSearch/Solr if you plan to have a lot of complex queries which do not fit well into cql3.

Comment: Thanks for the answer shutty. My usage pattern is not to get all variables of a person but to get all person values of a subgroup of variables. The input is a list of variables and the output is a list of persons and its values for each variable. It seems reasonable to me to use the variables as partition keys, but maybe I missing some important point here.

Comment: The column-per-variable solution was discarded because the variables are very dynamic and seems like a bad design to use an unbounded number of columns created dynamically by application code. We also tested the Cassandra collections and they did perform really poorly (to store the variables in a map), and some CQL capabilities were not available using collections.