# What is the best way to query Cassandra data from Node.JS including JOIN's, Full text search?

Tags: node.js, select, join, cassandra

What is the best way to query Cassandra data from Node.JS including JOIN's, Full text search?
I'm using "DataStax Node.js Driver for Apache Cassandra" but I can't JOIN tables, full text search, etc.

Comment: Cassandra doesn't support joins or full text search by itself. There is some things like spark and solr that you can use with Cassandra though if needed.

Comment: I can't find how to use Spark with Node.JS.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Inner Join in cassandra CQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16790297/inner-join-in-cassandra-cql)