# How to handle join query in Cassandra?

Tags: join, cassandra

How can I handle join query in CassandraDB? Is there a way to do these without using ApacheSpark or DataStax ODBC connectors? Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Inner Join in cassandra CQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16790297/inner-join-in-cassandra-cql)

Answer (score 2):

No, joins are basically antithetical to the core design concepts in Cassandra. They can only be done client side or via a distributed analytics tool.