# Spark - Scala : cannot perform multiple joins with spark-cassandra-connector

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I just want to perform a join with data (**cassandraTable1**, **cassandraTable2**) from 2 cassandra tables and a stream dataset (**partitionKeyStream**) from a kafka topic :

```
val joinedDataDf = (partitionKeyStream
  .join(cassandraTable1, partitionKeyStream("id") === cassandraTable1("id"), "left")
  .join(cassandraTable2, partitionKeyStream("id") === cassandraTable2("id"), "left")
)
```

I got the plan below with joinedDataDf.explain :

```
    == Physical Plan ==
SortMergeJoin [id#496], [id#492], LeftOuter
:- *(3) Sort [id#496 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
:  +- Exchange hashpartitioning(id#496, 200), true, [id=#230]
:     +- *(2) Project [id#496, latitude#112]
:        +- Cassandra Direct Join [id_number = id#496] key1.table1 - Reading (id_number, latitude) Pushed {}
:           +- *(1) Project ...
:              +- *(1) Filter ...
:                 +- StreamingRelation kafka, [key#8, value#9, topic#10, partition#11, offset#12L, timestamp#13, timestampType#14, headers#15]
+- *(5) Sort [id#492 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
   +- Exchange hashpartitioning(id#492, 200), true, [id=#237]
      +- *(4) Project [id#492, longitude#493]
         +- BatchScan[id#157, longitude#183] Cassandra Scan: key1.table2
```

When I execute my code with a single join (only data from table1 or table2), it seems all good. But with 2 joins, spark executes a Direct Join with the first, but does a full scan for the second.

I am using : spark 3.0.2 with the cassandra-spark-connector 3.0.1 and scala 2.12

Is there a way to only do direct joins ? How can i manage that ?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Inner Join in cassandra CQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16790297/inner-join-in-cassandra-cql)

Comment: Thank you for your reply @LeviRamsey. I tried to seperate the queries from table1 and table2 then perform a join between these 2 datasets => I had to add a watermark column as it is a stream-stream join. But, I am bloqued with the same full table scan ...